# AppFabric Issue i cant access object from different server and getting max buffersize error

Tags: c#, appfabric

When retrieving a cached object from my local machine, if the object size is not very big i can access successfully, but if the object is big I cant access from my local machine and I get this error:

> DataCacheException:ErrorCode ERRCA0016:SubStatus ES0001:
>
> The connection was terminated, possibly due to server or network problems
>   or serialized Object size is greater than MaxBufferSize on server.
>   Result of the request is unknown

This is my client confiugration.

```
<dataCacheClient requestTimeout="600000" channelOpenTimeout="12000" maxConnectionsToServer="1">
<localCache isEnabled="false" sync="TimeoutBased" ttlValue="300" objectCount="10000"/>
<clientNotification pollInterval="300" maxQueueLength="2147483647"/>
<hosts>
  <!--<host name="GB90033173N" cachePort="22233"/>-->
  <host name="GBUIZUGT01" cachePort="22233"/>
  <!--<host name="GBUAPPFAB01" cachePort="22233"/>
  <host name="GBUAPPFAB02" cachePort="22233"/>
  <host name="GBUAPPFAB03" cachePort="22233"/>-->
</hosts>
<securityProperties protectionLevel="None" mode="None"/>
<transportProperties connectionBufferSize="131072" maxBufferPoolSize="268435456"
                     maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxOutputDelay="2" channelInitializationTimeout="60000"
                     receiveTimeout="600000"/>
```

And this is my server configuration

```
<advancedProperties>
    <partitionStoreConnectionSettings leadHostManagement="false" />
    <securityProperties mode="None" protectionLevel="None">
         <authorization>
             <allow users="everyone" />
         </authorization>
    </securityProperties>
    <transportProperties maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
</advancedProperties>
<deploymentSettings>
    <deploymentMode value="RoutingClient" />
</deploymentSettings>
```

I can access a large object from the same server but I can't access from different server, and I'm getting this error.

Comment: When you say "I can access a large object from the same server" do you mean on the cache host itself? How are you running your cache client on the host?

Comment: Also, are client and server [in different domains](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/11/03/appfabric-cache-cache-servers-and-cache-clients-on-different-domains.aspx)?